# getting list of files inside an auto-imported folder by nitro

Tags: javascript, node.js, nuxtjs3, auto-import, nitro

I auto-imported an entire folder in nuxt 3 (server-side) by this:

```
nitro: {
  imports: {
    dirs: [
      './server/models/**.ts'
    ]
  }
},
```

now i need to have an array of all files inside `server/models` folder which are imported by nitro, so i can use it inside server js/ts codes